# rss feed, xml to json variable declaration

Tags: jquery, json, xml, variables, rss

I am using a jquery rss feed that converts the XML into JSON. It works great if you use the data that is pre-built into the code. I am trying to display a different data node that is coming through the xml and I keep getting the same error message:

> "Uncaught Error: Unknown token: {source}".

I cannot seem to figure out where to declare this variable, when I mimic the other variable declarations, I receive the unknown token error.

I would like to keep this in json format since it does not trigger the cross browser xml http request error.

here is my code.

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  var RSS = function (target, url, options, callback) {
    this.target       = target;

    this.url          = url;
    this.html         = [];
    this.effectQueue  = [];

    this.options = $.extend({
      ssl: false,
      host: 'www.feedrapp.info',
      limit: null,
      key: null,
      layoutTemplate: '<ul>{entries}</ul>',
      entryTemplate: '<li><a href="{url}">{title}</a><br/>{author}&nbsp;|&nbsp;{date}</li>',
      tokens: {},
      outputMode: 'json',
      dateFormat: 'dddd MMM Do',
      dateLocale: 'en',
      effect: 'show',
      offsetStart: false,
      offsetEnd: false,
      error: function () {
        console.log('jQuery RSS: url doesn\'t link to RSS-Feed');
      },
      onData: function () {},
      success: function () {}
    }, options || {});

    // The current SSL certificate is only valid for *.herokuapp.com
    if (this.options.ssl && (this.options.host === 'www.feedrapp.info')) {
      this.options.host = 'feedrapp.herokuapp.com';
    }

    this.callback = callback || this.options.success;
  };

  RSS.htmlTags = [
    'doctype', 'html', 'head', 'title', 'base', 'link', 'meta', 'style', 'script', 'noscript',
    'body', 'article', 'nav', 'aside', 'section', 'header', 'footer', 'h1-h6', 'hgroup', 'address',
    'p', 'hr', 'pre', 'blockquote', 'ol', 'ul', 'li', 'dl', 'dt', 'dd', 'figure', 'figcaption',
    'div', 'table', 'caption', 'thead', 'tbody', 'tfoot', 'tr', 'th', 'td', 'col', 'colgroup',
    'form', 'fieldset', 'legend', 'label', 'input', 'button', 'select', 'datalist', 'optgroup',
    'option', 'textarea', 'keygen', 'output', 'progress', 'meter', 'details', 'summary', 'command',
    'menu', 'del', 'ins', 'img', 'iframe', 'embed', 'object', 'param', 'video', 'audio', 'source',
    'canvas', 'track', 'map', 'area', 'a', 'em', 'strong', 'i', 'b', 'u', 's', 'small', 'abbr', 'q',
    'cite', 'dfn', 'sub', 'sup', 'time', 'code', 'kbd', 'samp', 'var', 'mark', 'bdi', 'bdo', 'ruby',
    'rt', 'rp', 'span', 'br', 'wbr'
  ];

  RSS.prototype.load = function (callback) {
    var apiProtocol = 'http' + (this.options.ssl ? 's' : '');
    var apiHost     = apiProtocol + '://' + this.options.host;
    var apiUrl      = apiHost + '?callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(this.url);

    // set limit to offsetEnd if offset has been set
    if (this.options.offsetStart && this.options.offsetEnd) {
      this.options.limit = this.options.offsetEnd;
    }

    if (this.options.limit !== null) {
      apiUrl += '&num=' + this.options.limit;
    }

    if (this.options.key !== null) {
      apiUrl += '&key=' + this.options.key;
    }

    $.getJSON(apiUrl, callback);
  };

  RSS.prototype.render = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.load(function (data) {
      try {
        self.feed    = data.responseData.feed;
        self.entries = data.responseData.feed.entries;
      } catch (e) {
        self.entries = [];
        self.feed    = null;
        return self.options.error.call(self);
      }

      var html = self.generateHTMLForEntries();

      self.target.append(html.layout);

      if (html.entries.length !== 0) {
        if ($.isFunction(self.options.onData)) {
          self.options.onData.call(self);
        }

        self.appendEntriesAndApplyEffects($('entries', html.layout), html.entries);
      }

      if (self.effectQueue.length > 0) {
        self.executeEffectQueue(self.callback);
      } else if ($.isFunction(self.callback)) {
        self.callback.call(self);
      }
    });
  };

  RSS.prototype.appendEntriesAndApplyEffects = function (target, entries) {
    var self = this;

    $.each(entries, function (idx, entry) {
      var $html = self.wrapContent(entry);

      if (self.options.effect === 'show') {
        target.before($html);
      } else {
        $html.css({ display: 'none' });
        target.before($html);
        self.applyEffect($html, self.options.effect);
      }
    });

    target.remove();
  };

  RSS.prototype.generateHTMLForEntries = function () {
    var self   = this;
    var result = { entries: [], layout: null };

    $(this.entries).each(function () {
      var entry       = this;
      var offsetStart = self.options.offsetStart;
      var offsetEnd   = self.options.offsetEnd;
      var evaluatedString;

      // offset required
      if (offsetStart && offsetEnd) {
        if (index >= offsetStart && index <= offsetEnd) {
          if (self.isRelevant(entry, result.entries)) {
            evaluatedString = self.evaluateStringForEntry(
              self.options.entryTemplate, entry
            );

            result.entries.push(evaluatedString);
          }
        }
      } else {
        // no offset
        if (self.isRelevant(entry, result.entries)) {
          evaluatedString = self.evaluateStringForEntry(
            self.options.entryTemplate, entry
          );

          result.entries.push(evaluatedString);
        }
      }
    });

    if (!!this.options.entryTemplate) {
      // we have an entryTemplate
      result.layout = this.wrapContent(
        this.options.layoutTemplate.replace('{entries}', '<entries></entries>')
      );
    } else {
      // no entryTemplate available
      result.layout = this.wrapContent('<div><entries></entries></div>');
    }

    return result;
  };

  RSS.prototype.wrapContent = function (content) {
    if ($.trim(content).indexOf('<') !== 0) {
      // the content has no html => create a surrounding div
      return $('<div>' + content + '</div>');
    } else {
      // the content has html => don't touch it
      return $(content);
    }
  };

  RSS.prototype.applyEffect = function ($element, effect, callback) {
    var self = this;

    switch (effect) {
      case 'slide':
        $element.slideDown('slow', callback);
        break;
      case 'slideFast':
        $element.slideDown(callback);
        break;
      case 'slideSynced':
        self.effectQueue.push({ element: $element, effect: 'slide' });
        break;
      case 'slideFastSynced':
        self.effectQueue.push({ element: $element, effect: 'slideFast' });
        break;
    }
  };

  RSS.prototype.executeEffectQueue = function (callback) {
    var self = this;

    this.effectQueue.reverse();

    var executeEffectQueueItem = function () {
      var item = self.effectQueue.pop();

      if (item) {
        self.applyEffect(item.element, item.effect, executeEffectQueueItem);
      } else if (callback) {
        callback();
      }
    };

    executeEffectQueueItem();
  };

  RSS.prototype.evaluateStringForEntry = function (string, entry) {
    var result = string;
    var self   = this;

    $(string.match(/(\{.*?\})/g)).each(function () {
      var token = this.toString();

      result = result.replace(token, self.getValueForToken(token, entry));
    });

    return result;
  };

  RSS.prototype.isRelevant = function (entry, entries) {
    var tokenMap = this.getTokenMap(entry);

    if (this.options.filter) {
      if (this.options.filterLimit && (this.options.filterLimit === entries.length)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return this.options.filter(entry, tokenMap);
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };

  RSS.prototype.getFormattedDate = function (dateString) {
    // If a custom formatting function is provided, use that.
    if (this.options.dateFormatFunction) {
      return this.options.dateFormatFunction(dateString);
    } else if (typeof moment !== 'undefined') {
      // If moment.js is available and dateFormatFunction is not overriding it,
      // use it to format the date.
      var date = moment(new Date(dateString));

      if (date.locale) {
        date = date.locale(this.options.dateLocale);
      } else {
        date = date.lang(this.options.dateLocale);
      }

      return date.format(this.options.dateFormat);
    } else {
      // If all else fails, just use the date as-is.
      return dateString;
    }
  };

  RSS.prototype.getTokenMap = function (entry) {
    if (!this.feedTokens) {
      var feed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.feed));

      delete feed.entries;
      this.feedTokens = feed;
    }

    return $.extend({
      feed:      this.feedTokens,
      url:       entry.link,
      author:    entry.author,
      date:      this.getFormattedDate(entry.publishedDate),
      title:     entry.title,
      body:      entry.content,
      shortBody: entry.contentSnippet,

      bodyPlain: (function (entry) {
        var result = entry.content
          .replace(/<script[\\r\\\s\S]*<\/script>/mgi, '')
          .replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');

        for (var i = 0; i < RSS.htmlTags.length; i++) {
          result = result.replace(new RegExp('<' + RSS.htmlTags[i], 'gi'), '');
        }

        return result;
      })(entry),

      shortBodyPlain: entry.contentSnippet.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, ''),
      index:          $.inArray(entry, this.entries),
      totalEntries:   this.entries.length,

      teaserImage:    (function (entry) {
        try {
          return entry.content.match(/(<img.*?>)/gi)[0];
        }
        catch (e) {
          return '';
        }
      })(entry),

      teaserImageUrl: (function (entry) {
        try {
          return entry.content.match(/(<img.*?>)/gi)[0].match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1];
        }
        catch (e) {
          return '';
        }
      })(entry)
    }, this.options.tokens);
  };

  RSS.prototype.getValueForToken = function (_token, entry) {
    var tokenMap = this.getTokenMap(entry);
    var token    = _token.replace(/[\{\}]/g, '');
    var result   = tokenMap[token];

    if (typeof result !== 'undefined') {
      return ((typeof result === 'function') ? result(entry, tokenMap) : result);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unknown token: ' + _token + ', url:' + this.url);
    }
  };

  $.fn.rss = function (url, options, callback) {
    new RSS(this, url, options, callback).render();
    return this; // Implement chaining
  };
})(jQuery);
```

and

```
 jQuery(function($) {
        $("#rss-feeds").rss("http://newsdesk-feeds.moreover.com/feed/a60eeb8d9fcdc35b.rss?n=200&text_format=text", {
          limit: 5,
          effect: 'slideFastSynced',

        })
      })
```

html:

```
<div id="rss-feeds"></div>
```

http://newsdesk-feeds.moreover.com/feed/a60eeb8d9fcdc35b.rss

You can clearly see in the xml there is a variable coming in named "Source" so why is it telling me it is unknown?

thank you!

Comment: Errors tell you where in the code the error is generated. That would help so anyone knows which part of all of this is causing problem

Comment: All seems to work fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/MLr4BgBaS1SJKQJyQUTk?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl yes it works when pulling in the AUTHOR variable. I want to pull i the SOURCE variable which is there in the xml and when i try and add the source variable the same way author is added, i get the error message. i need this to work with the SOURCE not AUTHOR.

Comment: Then update and fork demo to replicate problem. Not clear what you are doing or where error comes from. The code in question clearly works fine

Comment: @charlietfl i am trying to edit your plunk, but its not letting me, i am rebuilding to show you what i am trying to do

Comment: @charlietfl in the rss-plugin.js i am changing line 277 and adding:      source:    entry.source, so my variable is there and then i am adjusting my entry template on line 17 to pull the source. entryTemplate: '<li><a href="{url}">{title}</a><br/>{source}&nbsp;|&nbsp;{date}</li>',

Comment: @charlietfl i forked the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/bUQnXsBKqFhaivfJPMT3?p=preview

Comment: Looks like the whole thing is going through a third party site that converts it to json ...line 13 and line 71. They don't seem to send a lot back. I personally wouldn't even trust an unknown site like that and would consider using different approach like using Yahoo YQL

Comment: Can see exaclty what you get by putting this after line 269 `console.log(feed)`

Comment: @charlietfl its only showing the first opening data node, the actual news data is in a child node. so this does not really help since its not deep enough, i need to go deeper into the xml.

Comment: Either there are plugin options that tell that third party site to parse all the xml or you need different approach.

Comment: < [**jQRSS on GitHub**](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQRSS) >-< [***jsFiddle Example***](https://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/31y4y9gw/) >

Comment: @SpYk3HH this works great, thank you, but i am trying to pull the SOURCE data tag, not author. See the branching xml tree:

Comment: <item>
<title>
New capacity will more than replace retiring units in Florida in 2016
</title>

**<source>SNL FERC Power Report</source>**
<author>Meredith F Bearden</author>
<pubDate>11 Mar 2016 08:56:25 UT</pubDate>
<m:licenses xmlns:m="http://www.moreover.com/1.0/moreover">
<m:license>
<m:name>LexisNexis Licensed</m:name>
</m:license>
</m:licenses>
</item>

Comment: @SpYk3HH i cant seem to get this to work locally, i did a view frame source and copied all the code, then updated the links, console is saying: GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http%3A//newsdes…ery11100003609052859246731_1457708795446&num=5&output=json&_=1457708795447 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/xnuexLma/1/

Comment: it wont work locally without a slight tweek to the code. On about line 119 of my JS you have to change the link `gURL: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/",` to include `http`

Comment: thank you for the note tho, i'll make an update to my plugin in later today to make better for local testing, gota run for now

Comment: @SpYk3HH thank you so much you have been a major help!!! i really appreciate your time.

Comment: updated my github version to include fix for local testing

Comment: @SpYk3HH thank you so much!! this is so helpful. i apologize for not clarifying previously, but the data in the feed that is needed is headline, source and date, i am trying to combine the 2 fiddles now, my jquery is not great, but i do see that the source is using xml instead of json. is it possible to combine the 2?